# Python import Mariadb: 'ModuleNotFoundError'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb

I'm trying to use python to connect to a database that uses MariaDB, I'm taking the script on the MariaDB webpage but it gives me an error trying to import the MariaDB module. If I try to import this manually I get the same error message. This is the script:

```py
# Module Imports
import mariadb
import sys

# Connect to MariaDB Platform
try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="root",
        password="password",
        host="10.0.0.2",
        port=65500,
        database="main_db"

    )
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

# Get Cursor
cur = conn.cursor()
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path\to\myenv\scripts\connectdb.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mariadb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mariadb'
```

Prior to this, I checked that `mariadb` is properly installed:

```
C:\Users\user>pip install mariadb
Requirement already satisfied: mariadb in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.0.11)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

C:\Users\user>pip3 install mariadb
Requirement already satisfied: mariadb in c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (1.0.11)
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Also tried to move `mariadb` folder from where automatically installs to the same folder I have my "connectdb.py" file, but having the same result with one more error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\documents\pyth\last_connect.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mariadb
  File "c:\users\user\documents\pyth\mariadb\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._mariadb import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mariadb._mariadb'
>>> 

---------- FINISHED ----------
exit code: 2 status: 0
```

Comment: Maybe `python3 -m pip install mariadb` ?
Do you use a virtualenv ?

Comment: I'm getting the same result saying that it's already installed. Not using virtualenv.

Comment: How did you install mariadb-connector-python? You mixed pip and pip3 (Python2 and Python3). Binary wheels for windows don't have any dependencies and should work fine after installing them.

Comment: Try to uninstall mariab module: `pip3 uninstall mariadb` and reinstall it with `pip3 install --no-cache mariadb`.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably two different python interpreters installed. Check if you have selected the right one in your code editor.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, that i got the "**ModuleNotFoundError**" message.

I my case a simple `sudo` execution of `pip3 install mariadb` helped.

Comment: Running `pip install` with `sudo` is almost always a bad idea. Don't mix PyPI packages with system packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).